# d3.js does not show all map elements in the topojson

Tags: d3.js, geojson, topojson

A. I have downloaded two geojsons

1. world map
2. USA states

B. I then merge the two geojsons with `geojson-merge` on the commandline to give me a `world_map_with_USA_states.json`

`$ geojson-merge gz_2010_us_040_00_20m.json custom.geo.json > combined.json`

C. I then convert the `world_map_with_USA_states.json` to topojson on mapshaper.org

Loading the `world_map_with_USA_states.json` on https://mapshaper.org/ shows USA states and other countries

But d3.js does not show the USA states

**d3.js code**

```
let mapURl = 'world_map_with_USA_states.json'

let countriesData
const width = 900
const height = 600
const svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
                             .attr('width', width)
                             .attr('height', height)

const projection = d3.geoMercator().scale(140)
                                   .translate([width/2, height/1.4]) 

const path = d3.geoPath(projection)

const g = svg.append('g')

d3.json(mapURl)
  .then((data, error) =>{
      if (error){
          console.log(error)
      }else{
        console.log(data)
        countriesData = topojson.feature(data, data.objects.combined)

        g.selectAll('path').data(countriesData.features).enter().append('path')
                                                                .attr('class', 'country')
                                                                .attr('d', path)
      }
  })
```

**d3.js map (top)  Vs. mapshaper.org map (bottom)**

[image]

[image: mapshaper.org map with the same topojson]

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: What do you see if you set opacity to 0.5? Based on available info I'd say the states are behind the US feature.

Comment: @AndrewReid 
You are right.
As you can tell, I am not so good with the  GUI

Thanks!